# Laravel5 - After loggin in Auth method doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

I have problem with Auth method from Laravel5. After logging in, in my website, the HTML doc cannot see that "I am logged".

```
@if(Auth::user())
--><li class="userNav__item">
      <a href="#" class="userNav__link">
          <i class="icon-user-add userNav__image"></i>
           Hello, {{{  Auth::user()->name }}}
       </a>
   </li>
@endif
```

There is my "Loggin in" Controller

```
public function SignIn(Request $request){

    if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password])){
        return redirect('mainPage');
    }
    else{
        return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email' => 'Zły email lub hasło']);
    }
}
```

And routes.php file

http://pastebin.com/68CB0r7c <-- cannot post it in "Code" element..

And my question. Why Auth method in HTML doc is not working? What am i doing wrong? :(

One more ( it's funny... )
When i do something like this

```
public function SignIn(Request $request){

    if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password])){
        return view('layout.index');
       // return redirect('mainPage');
    }
    else{
        return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['email' => 'Zły email lub hasło']);
    }
}
```

The Auth::user method in HTML doc is working, but when i use "mainPage" route it's not working. LOL?

Comment: You do not give enough information to answer this question. Simply saying "it does not work" isn't enough. It appears you're using the built in authentication, so check the logs.

Comment: How can i check the logs? Sorry, it's my first time with Laravel..

Comment: Assuming Laravel 5.3: `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: The laravel.log is empty after loggin in.

Comment: What happens if you simply use the default controller/function that laravel already provides for login? 'LoginController@login' To post your data to?

Comment: Doesn't work too..

Comment: @killstreet Ok, works. Thanks mate :D

Answer (score 1):

Your form must be post but you

mainPage route is **get**

change it to post or **any**

```
Route::any('mainPage', function () {
    return view('layout.index');
});
```

This might solve your issue.

For authentication in Laravel most is done for you just have a look at

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authentication-quickstart

Comment: I have done everything from this tutorial and this doesn't work..  Changing to "any" doesn't work too :(

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a construct in your mainpage controller like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Comment: But what should i write in construct? I don't want the middleware, because everyone can go to every subpage even when they are not logged.